# Scrapyd - "spawnProcess not available since pywin32 is not installed" even after pywin32 installation

Tags: python, pywin32, scrapyd

I have latest version of Scrapy and latest version of Scrapyd available through pip install.

I am trying to run a spider via request to http://localhost:6800 (Scrapyd).

Scrapyd returns following error :

> builtins.NotImplementedError: spawnProcess not available since pywin32 is not installed.

I have installed pywin32 via pip :

> pip install pywin32

It was successfully installed as i got back this message :

> Successfully installed pywin32-227

What is the problem? Pywin32 is installed on my system but Scrapyd still says it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the other required dependecies? I was missing twisted and it was giving me a similar error.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to copy two dlls in `python3\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32` to `C:\Windows\System32`.